# Replace filters in Vaadin SQLContainer

Tags: java, vaadin7

I have table with SQLContainer. I have also form with filter. After change I want to replace filter.
First I remove all filters calling SQLContainer.removeAllContainerFilters():

```
 @Override
public void removeAllContainerFilters() {
    filters.clear();
    refresh();
}
```

It causes refresh. After removing filter I'm calling addContainerFilter():

```
public void addContainerFilter(Filter filter)
        throws UnsupportedFilterException {
    // filter.setCaseSensitive(!ignoreCase);

    filters.add(filter);
    refresh();
}
```

And second refresh is pefromed.

Can I replace filters so only on refresh will be performed?

Comment: Where are you calling those methods from?

Comment: I'm caaling this method after clicking "apply" button. Flow ist:
1. User set values on filter form and click apply
2. Old filters are removed by calling removeAllContainerFilters
3. Refresh is called
4. New filter is created with values from form
5. New filter is added by calling addContainerFilter
6. Refresh is called again.